# preg_replace space to line break with twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to replace space in string to line break.

**Before**

`1 2 3 4`

**After** preg_replace :

```
1
2
3
4
```

This is my code:

```
$m_cart = preg_replace('/\s/', '\n', $session->get('cart'));
return $this->render('FooSiteBundle:Site:bar.html.twig', array('cart' => $m_cart));
```

and this is my view with **twig**:

```
{{ cart }}
```

the result:

```
\n1\n2\n3\n4
```

but I would like to have

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newline escape sequence `\n` isn't interpreted by single-quote-delimited strings (as a point, /[no]/ escape sequences are)

The simple answer is to just change `'\n'` to `"\n"`.

I invite you to [read more about PHP's string delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and how they differ

Comment: it work fine in my source code but doesn't work in my html page

Comment: If what you want is different lines in HTML you need to add <br> instead of \n

Comment: @Alex its being escaped by Twig

Answer (score 3):

Would `nl2br` help?

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html

so try:

```
{{ cart|nl2br }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `'\n'` to `"\n"`. That is, add double quotes. PHP parses them differently, and having double quotes enables you to use special characters like `\n`.

Comment: I'm out of votes for today, but I'll try to remember to +1 this tomorrow. Good answer!